# Is there a file manager that can serially number files and subfolders in the currently viewed directory?

Tags: python, vim, filemanager, ncurses

Is there a file manager that can serially number files and sub-folders in the currently viewed directory?

Comment: Given the tags, are you looking for a GUI or CLI solution? Also do you mean to rename the files, or just display a numbered list without modifying anything? And what sort order should be used and what columns/info should be included?

Comment: This question is actually to answer a question that was closed, which I asked to be re-opened, and which is now deleted. You can see it here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1135119/is-there-a-file-manager-that-can-serially-number-files-and-subfolders-in-the-cur

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Ranger* can do that. *Ranger* is a VIM-inspired file manager for the console available in the universe repository of all currently supported versions of Ubuntu. The GitHub page is [here](https://github.com/ranger/ranger).

This answer is not meant to describe how to use *Ranger* but specifically to indicate that numbering files and folders is possible using *Ranger*.

---

Users can edit *~/.config/ranger/rc.conf* to change the default setting of

```
# Disable displaying line numbers in main column
set line_numbers false
```

to

```
# Disable displaying line numbers in main column
set line_numbers absolute
```

With `set line_numbers absolute`, a user can jump to specific a entry in the main (middle) by typing `Ngg` where `N` is the line number to the *left* of the file or folder name.

The following images, of Ranger in Ubuntu 19.04, shows line numbering in effect in the main (middle) column for the home folder and for */etc*.

**Home folder**

[image: folders and files serially numbered in the home folder]

**/etc**

[image: /etc folder]